# ReferenceError: poll is not defined for Community Poll joomla component

Tags: component, joomla-3.4

I have been working on community poll joomla component for my website when user voting for some polls it shows below js error.

> ReferenceError: poll is not defined

why this error show is there any js conflicting or some settings from community poll component settings. please suggest some solution asap.

Comment: A solution would require some code to be shown. We can't help without seeing anything

Comment: here it is my site link [link](http://actionfigureking.com/toy-and-comic-book-related-breaking-news/mine])

Comment: Well `poll` is not defined, so have you try debugging your code and tried to figure out why it isn't? You should start making full use of `console.log()`

Comment: thnks@Lodder for ur reply in error_log file show  `require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/actionfi/public_html/plugins/system/nnframework/helpers/parameters.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/actionfi/public_html/templates/system/modal.php on line 33`

Comment: removed all the errors from error log file still voting js error is shown.

Comment: Yes, because it's a **Javascript** error. In the Ajax request, after the `.done()` function, you're using `poll` but it isn't defined

Comment: yes @Lodder, i am not good in js so please suggest me how should i define poll

Comment: I'm not going to start going through all your JS and debug it. You should start debugging it by yourself by using `console.log()`

Comment: @Lodder: issue is resolved... poll value is passed in npoll variable rather then poll so i should passes npoll parameter now its working thnks lodder for your suggestions.

Comment: @paypal - Please add this as an answer and accept it so people know it has been solved ;)

Comment: sry i am new in stackoverflow so i don't know how to accept the comments answer and one more request my name is payal not paypal....

Comment: You will see a big answer text area below. Post it in there

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved.by replacing poll variable from npoll variable in anywhere .js because there is no poll variable is defined and npoll containing poll article value. thanks joomla beta this answer is accepted.